# axlsx serialize spreadsheet to string

Tags: ruby, axlsx

For testing purposes, I'd like to serialize an axlsx spreadsheet to a string. The [axlsx documentation](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) indicates it is possible to "Output to file or StringIO". But I haven't found documentation or a code sample that explains how to output to a StringIO. How is it done?

Answer (score 4):

From the [code](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/cf4da4b12726bd6049b9d68652685018cf7f033e/lib/axlsx/package.rb#L98):

```
# Serialize to a stream
s = package.to_stream()
File.open('example_streamed.xlsx', 'w') { |f| f.write(s.read) }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the end, an [xlsx] file is zip archive containing multiple xml files and other assets. You can use Package#to_stream to generate an IO stream for streaming purposes, but viewing that archive as a string is probably not what you are looking to do.

If you are just looking to investigate the xml for a specific Worksheet, you can use Worksheet#to_xml_string which will return a String object with all the goodies in there. (That is how worksheet validation works, we parse that XML and validate it against the schema for the object)

Hope this help!